# Is it legal to receive/send "gifts" of Non-Trivial Amounts to a "friend"?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, gift-tax

This can be illustrated in many ways. But for the sake of a concrete example, let's assume a sample scenario: We have an employer (Mr-A) and his employee (Mr-B) also happens to be his "**good friend**". The annual wage is $x which naturally is subject to income taxes. Here's the catch though: **$x is a  low number** by "normal standards" (e.g. ~$5 annual wage, or ~$50 or ~$500 or ~$5000.. it doesn't really matter).

However, Mr-A gifts his *friend* items and cash amounting to below $14k, or let's just put it at **below $10k** annually. This can be ~$9000 or below but it doesn't really matter. Mr-A  does not expect to get anything in return from Mr-B, so it is a "**true gift**". (Though ***perhaps*** if Mr-B decides to stop working, Mr-A may also ***arbitrarily*** decide not to continue his gifts to Mr-B.)

On top of that, Mr-A's spouse also gifts Mr-B  items and cash amounting to **below $10k** annually, and **each** of Mr-A's other friends and relatives also gifts Mr-B items and cash amounting to **below $10k** annually.

In other words, in total Mr-B could've received "true gifts" amounting to over $20k, $50k, or even over $100k a year in cash and items.

Is such a thing legal?

Are there any ways to work around it? (akin to the [irish tax loophole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_Irish_arrangement) used by Apple and Linkedin for corporate taxes which used to work)

Comment: No idea about the US, but in the UK any scheme of this sort is classed as a tax avoidance scheme and you have to declare what you are doing to the Inland Revenue. In this specific example they would almost certainly decide that the gifts are really salary and should be taxed as such.

Comment: @Vicky, I don't get it.. exactly *what* do I have to declare? Do you mean in the UK any time someone receives gifts he have to report it? Or do you mean any time someone receive gifts from people "related" to his employer he have to report it?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is one of those you need to ask a lawyer questions, so IANAL and this is a non-legal opinion yada, yada, but in order to be considered a gift it must given with no expectation of getting anything in return. Thus, your claim of getting only a $5 salary will certainly be considered tax avoidance in any country because I'm certain that the $130K has the expectation of your working for the family. It'll be hard to prove that you are donating your time while still getting money. The IRS will look at what a person doing your job should earn and see that $60 is not reasonable.

Comment: @JoeCoderGuy, what do you mean by "it's not really a gift?". Based on the above circumstances, is it considered tax fraud? Also, since each person's gift is under $13k USD, is it right to say that they need not be declared?

Comment: @Pace:I would say that what you describe is ok as long as you (or immediate family member) doesn't work for "your friend". Otherwise, it is obvious by a "preponderance of the evidence" that your scheme is a means of tax fraud. You know the IRS isn't going to like your scheme and if it goes to court, do you really believe that you will be able to convince a jury that the $130K is just a gift and you would be working for "your friend" for $60 a year, even without the "gift".

Comment: You have the best friends ever, I wish I had friends who wanted to give me $130,000 a year no strings attached.  Errr, wait... this is blatant tax fraud as best I can tell on both your part as well as the business. So I guess the answer is, "no, you don't have to pay any taxes - but be prepared to face significant fines/jail time when the IRS finds out."

Comment: In addition to being tax fraud, what would you do if at the end of the year your friend decided to not gift you.  Alternatively, what would your employer do if you decide to quit shortly after receiving your "gifts".  If your employer goes bankrupt, I am pretty sure gifts can be clawed back, but salary not.

Comment: When the IRS CID suspects tax fraud their opening salvo can include freezing all of the targets assets.  From there the burden becomes on the targets to prove the IRS wrong.  Paying a lawyer to try and do so when the IRS has all your bank accounts is easier said than done.  See (among others in the thread):  http://www.popehat.com/2013/05/06/does-prenda-believe-in-no-win-scenarios-because-judge-wright-just-gave-them-one/#comment-1043402  IANAL but you and your friend appear to be juggling carboys of nitroglycerine.

Comment: To be clear - The current (2013) US gift limit is $14K/yr. The lifetime limit is currently $5.25M. But as everyone responding has noted, the proposal is tax fraud. The gifts are typically used by family to pass on to the next generation, or used to fund college savings accounts.

Comment: @Pacerier what he's saying is if your employer ends up taken to court by a creditor, those "gifts" may be taken from you to pay off his debts.

Ask Bernie Madoff's wife if she gets to keep her jewelry.

Comment: I don't think this question should have been asked. What is being asked about is pretty fraudulent. In addition, I don't think the question (as it's currently worded) is likely to be very useful for those who aren't trying to be fraudulent.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Agreed, the question as asked is "Can I/my commit massive tax fraud by using a loophole in the tax laws". [The answer... is No.](http://youtu.be/NKJKjXAY5bs?t=1m17s)

Comment: Using loopholes in the laws is not fraud. If it is legal, then it is legal. Even if that's not what the government intended. Attempting to legally get around a law is not breaking the law or committing fraud. That's why trusts and charitable foundations were invented. The rich get to pass money to their heirs without paying taxes. Not the intent of inheritance taxes, but perfectly legal. In fact, I'm quite certain that given enough money, some variation on the OP scheme could be made quite legal. It's just us poor slubs who can't afford to implement the loopholes that get stuck with the bill.

Comment: @deworde, What Dunk said. **If it's legal, then it's legal.** Law and morality are two separate things. Ethics questions are related to philosophy.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Pacerier I understand that, but what I'm saying is that unless you were not perfect (and this site will never get you there) you're taking on massive risk for any mistake.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm I disagree.  A financially naive person might very well accept such an arrangement at face value not knowing they are doing something wrong.

Comment: @Dunk your premise is wrong. You're assuming that this is legal, and the issue is just defending yourself in court. This is not so. It's not the attorney costs that are a barrier, it's the law - the scheme is illegal. There are other loopholes, but that doesn't mean that any illegal thing becomes a loophole. Your claims about rich people avoiding inheritance taxes is nonsense and charitable foundations have nothing to do with this. You sound like some kid who wants a toy from a store for free, points at another kid walking with a different toy and says "he has it, why can't I take this?"

Comment: @Pacerier That's not what Dunk said. He said "If you're rich, laws don't matter". Do you think you're rich enough, even if the claim is true?

Comment: Also, the Irish tax loophole is now closed, but even before it was - it was for corporate taxes, based on sourcing income and not repatriating it. You're talking about *recharacterizing* income. Again - completely irrelevant for your question, and just shows that you want a satisfaction that breaking a law is OK because "Others do it", not an actual answer.

Comment: @littleadv, Yes I'm aware that it's for corporate taxes, as is written in the question. It's listed in the question because it is the closest analogy and it helps to make it clear what the question is aiming at.

Comment: @Pacerier but there's no analogy. Your question is about re-characterizing earned income as a gift, and your analogy is not repatriating income sourced outside of the country. These are completely unrelated issues that don't even look similar.

Comment: @littleadv, The  similarity between the actors in  both systems is the intention to disobey the spirit of the law, yet abide by the interpretation of the statements.

Comment: @Pacerier there's nothing disobedient in the dutch-irish sandwich. No laws are broken. No income is recharacterized. The companies take advantage of the international corporate tax regime, but they don't break any laws in any country, and don't misrepresent the facts.

Comment: @littleadv - I already commented that this particular situation would certainly be considered tax fraud. It is too obvious on the intent. However, using loopholes in the law that nobody thought of at the time the bill was written is another matter. e.g. Companies can't deduct obscene compensation packages for company execs any more but they can give them enormous amounts of stock options instead.

Comment: I'm sure if the OP's situation were available to only a "select" group of people and not possibly EVERYBODY then a decent tax attorney would find a way to legitimize exactly what the OP wants to do. Likely through a few phone calls to people they know in congress. However, since the OP's situation would open the floodgates to avoiding taxes then you can bet congress won't get themselves involved and the IRS can make up their own rules and deny the OP's plan. After all, compensating via stock options instead of directly through cash is pretty much the same thing but when you have connections...

Comment: @Dunk *Companies can't deduct obscene compensation packages for company execs* - say what? Of course they can. Why wouldn't they? I'm not sure you understand what a "loophole" is. It is not making something illegal into legal, not at all.

Comment: Tax code 162 (m) was written to explicitly curb excessive compensation. In particular, it denies companies from being allowed to take deductions on highly compensated execs unless certain conditions are met. Most companies violate this law but for some reason they get away with it; probably because they enlist the help of their other extremely wealthy friends and pay off their congress people to intervene if the IRS wants to pursue the matter. Many companies don't want the hassle and simply forego the tax deduction for their highly compensated execs.

Answer (score 26):

> Am I right to say that no tax needs to be given for the annual ~$130k
>   USD, since they are considered as annual gift tax exclusion?

Not only that you're wrong, but it also looks like a tax **fraud**, not just mere avoidance. You'll have hard time proving to any judge or jury that the gifts are "in good faith".

By the way, $5 a month is below minimum wage.

Comment: @Pacerier with stock option grants, that are considered salary for the purpose of minimum wage.

Comment: @little -  There are actually a fair number of exemptions to minimum wage laws. In particular, higher level management, administrative staff, sales staff and seasonal workers.

Comment: @Dunk depends on State really, for many small employers Federal minimum wage doesn't apply.

Comment: @Pacerier they're not gifts, they're salary. Is salary not taxable?

Comment: @littleadv, So that's not too much point in the $1 salary after all right?

Comment: not really, IMHO

Comment: @littleadv, Re "*$5 a month is below minimum wage*"; I mean the actual number doesn't really matter, we can up it to minimum wage and the essence of the question still stands.

Comment: @Pacerier but you didn't, did you?

Comment: @littleadv, ?​​​͏͏͏

Comment: @Pacerier my point is that your question very clearly described a tax evasion. So now that you understood why, you're trying to change the question. But even then, you cannot possibly claim that the extra money the employers give you is a gift since there's quid pro quo - they got something in return. The burden of proof that the gift is genuine and has no relationship to your working there is very high, because it very rarely makes sense.

Comment: @littleadv, The "*burden of proof that the gift is genuine and has no relationship to your working there is very high*" is **exactly** why this question is asked. It is **looking for a mechanism to** **convert** a scenario of (*possible* adjudication of) tax evasion into a scenario of legally permitted avoidance.

Comment: @Pacerier not sure what you mean by this. Evasion is illegal, avoidance is legal. You're trying to make something that is illegal to look legal? It will still be illegal.

Answer (score 21):

This is tax fraud, plain and simple.

I recently wrote an article [The Step Transaction Doctrine](http://rothmania.net/step-transaction-doctrine/), in which I explain that a series of events may each be legal, but aggregate to one transaction and the individual steps are ignored.

In this case, it goes beyond that, by accepting $5/mo you are already outside the tax code. As littleadv noted, you can't work for a legitimate business for free and not expect to have some kind of issue. The $14K/yr gift isn't a bona fide gift, but ties to that work.

Comment: I mean, the point of the question is how to make it **not** a tax fraud? ...What are some of the technicalities or crucial steps that need to be taken for it to be **not** a tax fraud?

Comment: Simple, you claim every cent, save for a sub-$25 valued gift at Holiday time.

Answer (score 13):

In almost all cases, gifts from employers are considered taxable compensation, based on the employer-employee nature of the relationship. Furthermore, cash gifts are always considered to be intended as wages, regardless of how you receive the money.

Furthermore, regardless of whether you expect to receive anything in return (such as contractual consideration) or whether the amounts are large enough to be declared as taxable personal gifts, it is likely that the IRS would consider these payments to be "disguised wages", as these payments would fail several tests that the IRS uses to determine whether benefits provided by the employer are non-taxable, including:

1. Must be occasional or infrequent
2. Must be of nominal value (usually below $100.00, my company's guidelines are even lower)
3. Can never be in cash, with the exception of travel & meals to facilitate overtime.

I'd recommend reviewing IRS publication 535 [here](http://www.irs.gov/file_source/pub/irs-pdf/p535.pdf), as well as publication 15-B [here](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p15b/ar02.html) for more on what constitutes taxable wages & benefits.

It seems very unlikely to me that you could make a persuasive legal defense in which you claimed to be working full-time for $60.00 per year and just happened to be receiving large personal gifts of $130,000.00. In my opinion it seems much more likely that these payments would be found to be taxable wages for services rendered.

Comment: And if it comes to the IRS audit, I'm pretty sure its going to be treated as a **criminal** investigation against both the employer and the employee (not only income taxes are at stake here, but also state taxes, FUTA, FICA and disability insurance, etc).

Comment: OASDI, Medicare tax withholdings as well...

Comment: +1 - and in this case, the employer would not be able to deduct the payments as a business expense, which would be costly for him.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer yes given the business expense implications it seems umlikely that an employer in a legitimate business would offer to compensate anyone in this way unless the main business itself was also evading taxes